# CMake script for CUDA 6.0 with C++11

Tags: macos, c++11, cuda, cmake

I am working on a 64-bit Mac OSX 10.9 for my CUDA 6.0 + Boost 1.55.0 + OpenCV 2.4.9 project, compiled using a makefile, but since I will eventually test it on 64-bit Windows 8.1, I thought I'd get acquainted with CMake. Since I am using C++11, I am generating object files for the C++ code with clang++ (version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40), which g++ now links to in mavericks) and CUDA code with nvcc separately, then linking the object files together for the final executable in my makefile.

I have no idea how to do this in CMake though. I tried compiling the CUDA code as a static library (using both CMake built-ins and FindCUDA.cmake utilities) and then linking it, but that did not work. I have not been able to find a solution online which takes C++11 into account.

Here is my CMake script so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(pupil_tracker)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(include/cuda)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};-gencode arch=compute_20, code=sm_20)
#set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER clang++) # Fails with 'invalid argument '-std=c++11' not allowed with 'C/ObjC''

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}) # So CMake finds FindOpenCV.cmake
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY(cuda_obj STATIC src/cuda/Tools.cu) # Doesn't seem to work

add_executable(main src/main.cpp src/CenteredHaarFeature.cpp src/PupilTracker.cpp src/Tools.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(main ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(main ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(main ${cuda_obj})

install(TARGETS main DESTINATION ../bin)
```

If all fails, I'll have to try and set up a MSVC project on my Windows machine to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` can interfere with the NVCC compilation so you have to be careful about where you put them.

I recreated your setup with a really simple example using only the CUDA library. After rearranging and editing a few of the CMake commands I was able to compile and run the program.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(pupil_tracker)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(include/cuda)

# removed a space and added C++11 functionality (note the double '--' for NVCC)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20;--std=c++11)
set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER clang++) # shouldn't fail anymore

# didn't test with Boost
# find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
# include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# didn't test with OpenCV
# set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}) # So CMake finds FindOpenCV.cmake
# find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
# include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY(cuda_obj STATIC src/cuda/Tools.cu) # works for me now

# moved the CXX flags to after the cuda_add_library call
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")
add_executable(main src/main.cpp src/Tools.cpp) # only used one c++ class for this test

# target_link_libraries(main ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(main ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
# target_link_libraries(main ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(main cuda_obj) # changed ${cuda_obj} to cuda_obj

install(TARGETS main DESTINATION ../bin)
```

The project directory setup can be inferred from the CMake file but for clarification it looks like:

ProjectDir:

- CMakeLists.txt
- *include*

  - Tools.hpp
  - *cuda*

    - Tools.cuh
- *src*

  - main.cpp
  - Tools.cpp
  - *cuda*

    - Tools.cu

Tools.cuh:

```
#ifndef TOOLS_CUH
#define TOOLS_CUH

extern "C"
{
    void do_cuda_stuff();
}

#endif
```

Tools.cu:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
    __global__
    void do_cuda_stuff_kernel()
    {
        int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        printf("Hello from thread %d!\n", idx);
    }

    void do_cuda_stuff()
    {
        // 2 blocks, 3 threads each
        do_cuda_stuff_kernel<<<2, 3>>>();
        cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // to print results
    }
}
```

Tools.hpp:

```
#ifndef TOOLS_HPP
#define TOOLS_HPP

class Tools
{
public:
    int execute();
};

#endif
```

Tools.cpp:

```
#include "Tools.hpp"
#include "Tools.cuh"

int Tools::execute()
{
    do_cuda_stuff();
    return 0;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Tools.hpp"

int main(void)
{
    Tools tools;
    return tools.execute();
}
```

Output:

```
Hello from thread 3!
Hello from thread 4!
Hello from thread 5!
Hello from thread 0!
Hello from thread 1!
Hello from thread 2!
```

I'm currently using CUDA 7.5 and OSX 10.10 but I think the biggest issue was the placement of the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable. Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: It's been a while, so I can readily confirm your answer, but thanks for the response. I wasn't aware that CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS could interfere as it did, so that might very well have been the issue, and so I accepted your answer. I had a similar project layout, but I got it to work even though I had the flags before the compilation, it looks like. I removed the CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY, and instead added the source directly to the add_executable function. I also added set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON) which, IIRC, alleviates compilation of C/C++ and CUDA.

Comment: Yeah I figured you had moved on but hopefully it helps a few others who stumble across this problem. I just recently learned of the seperable compilation option so ill check it out but I'm glad you got it working

Comment: Of course, and I appreciate the help anyways. This might become useful if I work with CUDA again :)