# How to properly link cuda files to cpp files using cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cuda

I am learning how to use cmake to compile a project containing .cpp files
and .cu files. Currently I am working with a toy example of only two files one main.cpp and kernel.cu. The files is

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
extern void kernel_wrapper(int *a, int *b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;

    printf("Input: a = %d, b = %d\n",a,b);
    kernel_wrapper(&a, &b);
    printf("Ran: a = %d, b = %d\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

kernel.cu:

```
//#include "cuPrintf.cu"
#include <stdio.h>
__global__ void kernel(int *a, int *b){
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
//  cuPrintf("tx = %d\n", tx);
    switch( tx ){
    case 0:
        *a = *a + 10;
        break;
    case 1:
        *b = *b + 3;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void kernel_wrapper(int *a, int *b){
//  cudaPrintfInit();
    //cuPrintf("Anything...?");
    printf("Anything...?\n");
    int *d_1, *d_2;
    dim3 threads( 2, 1 );
    dim3 blocks( 1, 1 );

    cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_1, sizeof(int) );
    cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_2, sizeof(int) );

    cudaMemcpy( d_1, a, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( d_2, b, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

    kernel<<< blocks, threads >>>( d_1, d_2 );
    cudaMemcpy( a, d_1, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    cudaMemcpy( b, d_2, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    printf("Output: a = %d\n", a[0]);
    cudaFree(d_1);
    cudaFree(d_2);

//  cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout, true);
//  cudaPrintfEnd();
}
```

The cmake file is inspired from this post: [CMake script for CUDA 6.0 with C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413317/cmake-script-for-cuda-6-0-with-c11?rq=1)

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread -lpthread")
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project( CUDAAndCP )
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

# For compilation ...
# Specify target & source files to compile it from

# Pass options to NVCC
set(
    CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS
    ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};
    -O3 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;
    --std=c++11
    )

cuda_add_library(kernel_obj kernel.cu)
cuda_add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(main kernel_obj)
```

I do get the main binary file compiled but when I run it, the result is

```
Input: a = 2, b = 3
Anything...?
Output: a = 2
Ran: a = 2, b = 3
```

Instead of

```
Input: a = 2, b = 3
Anything...?
Output: a = 2
Ran: a = 12, b = 6
```

I got the correct main binary file by running

```
g++ -c main.cpp
nvcc -c kernel.cu
nvcc -o main main.o kernel.o
```

So it seems that the cuda file didn't link correctly to the main binary. I really don't understand why and any help is appreciated!

I am running this on ubuntu 14.04, cuda 7.5 and cmake 3.2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the update m.s. . I tried to put the int main() {} into the kernel.cu and now there should not be any link issue since it is only a single file. Yet cuda_add_executable(main kernel.cu) still compile and still give wrong result. The gpu kernel didn't run at all. But nvcc kernel.cu produce a correct binary.

Comment: Funky thing is, when I comment out the set{nvcc ...} section in cmakeList.txt, the resulting main is correct! Anybody has idea what causes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's something tricky about code generation. My platform is the same as yours, and I'm using a GTX 980.

The real problem is `arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;`. If change this to 52, everything works.

And if built with bare command line, CUDA 7.5 `nvcc` is default to generate `compute_20` and `sm_20` code.